# Windows Update errors on Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 x64

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I've recently installed Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 x64 and there are more than 200 updates available, I let Windows Update download and install the updates but when the computer restarts, the logon (blue with logos) screen gets stuck more than five hours in the step 5 of 5 and it says "reverting changes". Finally when the update is "complete", only less of 20 updates were properly installed.

[image]

This happened two times (first time I got rid of waiting and used System Recovery), is a waste of time, I can't use my computer when Windows Update is working because svchost.exe and TrustedInstaller.exe uses more than 2 GB of system memory.

My system specs:

- Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 x64 clean install
- AMD Phenom X3 8400 at 2.1 GHz
- 4 GB DDR2 RAM
- ATI Radeon HD4550
- 360 GB HDD with 250+ GB available

**Edit:**
After first trial, I've deleted SoftwareDistribution content, executed Windows Update troubleshooting package "WindowsUpdateDiagnostic.diagcab".

Comment: copy the folder **C:\windows\logs\cbs** to your desktop, zip it and share the zip (OneDrive, Dropbox)

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows 7, you sometimes have to force updates to be installed in a different order than the order normally chosen automatically, by choosing only a few updates to be installed, NOT including the first one shown on the list.  Once you are able to get at least one more update installed this way, try only the first update on the list, to see if it will now install.  If not, you will have to try installing more updates that are NOT first on the list.